# VB script error in ArcGIS 10.2, error '13', Type mismatch, when using Application

Tags: vbscript, arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

The original question was posted on

[question link](https://community.esri.com/thread/218135-vb-script-error-in-arcgis-102-error-13-type-mismatch-when-using-application)

Error occurs at the yellow highlighted line. 
[image: error line]

However such syntax seems to be correct in [ArcGIS developer guide](http://www.socsci.flinders.edu.au/geog/sisl/ESRI_Library/Developing_with_ArcObjects/Desktop_Developers_Guide.pdf)

see page 163
[image: page 163]

Many thanks if someone can resolve this.

Comment: VBScript doesn't support typed variables (`Dim var As type`), so this code doesn't look like it's VBScript in the first place. Is it VB.net or a VBA dialect?

Answer (score 0):

I answer the question myself. See the link [the 1st comment](https://community.esri.com/thread/218135-vb-script-error-in-arcgis-102-error-13-type-mismatch-when-using-application)

As the library name was changed in ArcGis 10.2, so instead of using `Set pApp = Application`  or  `Set pApp = ArcMap.Application`, it should be `Set pApp = esriArcMap.Application`.

We can use Object Browser to identify the library name.

[image: Object Browser]

[image: Search in the Browser]